# Amortized cost of decimal counter

Tags: algorithm-analysis, amortized-analysis

Can somebody tell me what the **lowest** amortized cost for the increment operation of a decimal counter is?

I can show the costs are O(1) and with max amortized costs of 2 (similar to a binary counter), but is this the lowest possible value?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Every increment must require at least one operation so you can't possibly get better than $O(1)$, which is what you've got.

Comment: @DavidRicherby We may want to look beyond Big-Oh.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!